# ExtJS Carousel Adding Items Dynamically

Tags: extjs, extjs6

I have the follow ExtJS Carousel, but I can't make it work...

```
title: 'Pictures',
items: [{
    xtype: 'carousel',
    listeners: {
        initialize: 'onCarouselInitialize'
    }
}]
```

In the ViewController:

```
onCarouselInitialize: function(component, eOpts) {
    var url = 'resources/images/sample.jpg'; // valid URL
    component.add({
        xtype: 'image',
        src: url
    });
}
```

...and nothing happen!
I couldn't find an example populating the carousel dynamically.
Some help, please!!!!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: I was missing defining the height of the container panel